# Express.js file-system based router

Tags: node.js, express

I just would like to ask, is it possible to do file-system based routing with express.js routes? Something like Next.js has.

Comment: what do mean with "Something like Next.js has"? Next.js router is for the frontend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I do not recommend this as it can turn out to be a security issue. However if you really want to, it is quite easy to do. You can just listen to app.get("*"). An example shown below:

```js
let path = require("path")
let express = require("express")
let app = express()
let fs = require("fs")

app.get("*", (req,res) => {
    let filePath = path.join(__dirname, "routes", req.path)
    if(!fs.existsSync(filePath)) return res.sendStatus(404)
    res.sendFile(filePath)
})

app.listen(80)
```

This recurses and loads any file that may be there in the "routes" folder (or any subdirectories). I did this with html so i did sendFile(), however I believe it should work with .render() too.

I highly recommend against this as it *can* potentially allow people to climb up your directory structure with some messing around with the path they try to fetch.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I will try to extend this by implementing some security measures, but this is exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-file-routing

Try this. It lists all available files and enable routing only for them. Also this supports path parameters.